# Two Miller integrator in series

Tags: integrator

[image]

How may I deduce the time constants from these output waveforms?
For \$V_{o1}\$ may I write \$\tau=1/2\pi f\$, where \$f=1/T=1/1ms=1KHz\$?

Comment: I'd start with trying to find the transfer function of the system. From this you can usually figure out the time constant.

Comment: Hit your local university's engineering library and dig out an OLD textbook on analog computers.  What you have here are two absolutely classic analog computer integrators.

Comment: @klamb which is actually precisely what I did. Isn't it 1/(s*tau) where s=jw? For Vo1 that is.

Comment: Hint: Part b)  question is similar to Part a) answer

Comment: If I assume R1 = 1kΩ for  0s to 0.5ms the current is equal to I = 1V/1kΩ = 1mA and the capacitor voltage need to change from 0V to -1V Hence C = Q/V = (I*t)/V = (1mA *0.5ms)/1V = 500nF, so the time constant is 0.5ms. And the time constant for a second integrator is also equal to 0.5ms. Because if you do the integration you will found that Vo2 = 0.5V at  T = 0.5ms only when t2 = 0.5ms; for t2 = 1ms --->Vo2 = 0.25V; For t2 = 0.25mS ---->Vo2 = 1V.

Comment: @G36 I managed showing that explicitly via integration :-). As for the second part (section b) -- could I do this: (1V-1mV)*1ms/tau1=Vo1=1.998V, and (1.998V-1mV)*1ms/tau2=Vo2=3.994V? Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: http://slideplayer.com/slide/5060393/16/images/25/DC+problems+in+miller+integrator.jpg

Answer (score 1):

We know the inverting terminal of the opamp is going to have the same voltage as the non-inverting terminal.

Given that information, you can calculate the current across the resistor which is the current into the capacitor (since no current flows into the op-amp inverting terminal) and then you can go from there.

Comment: you're suggesting that in order to determine the transfer function, right?

Comment: The question doesn't ask for that. It asks for time constants. I am telling you how to calculate the capacitance and resistance as to calculate that.

Comment: Doing that I still get \$j\omega \tau = 1\$

Comment: I am suggesting you solve it in the time domain, given that you are given graphs in the time domain.

Comment: Well, I know that (1-0)/R1=(0-(-1))/sC1, is that better? How is that helpful?

Comment: s is the complex variable which is used for frequency domain. In the time domain your equation is 1/R1 = C*(dVo1/dt)

Comment: So I get that the slope of the Vo1 graph represents -1/tau. So tau1 = 0.5ms. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

\$dV/dt=1V/0.5~ms~= 2V/ms~~=I_C/C\$,
If C=1uF , At t=0.5ms Vo1=1V, Ic=200uA=1V/R1, R1=5k then
**R1C1 = 5ms**  from the 1st step.

At t=1ms Vo1 averages 0.5V and if C2 =1uF
with Vo2(1ms) = 1V Then R2= 1V/1ms = 1k so **R2C2= 1ms** from the 2nd input -ve step.